# Should popViewController be called from the parent or child ViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I can pop a view controller from a `UINavigationController`'s stack by calling `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` either from the parent view controller that instantiated it, or from the child view controller itself. Which way is preferable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose the answer is "whatever makes the most sense"; as you said, you can call `popViewControllerAnimated:` from the parent, child, or even some other class that holds a reference to the navigation controller.

For most apps, the child view will contain a "back" or "done" button or some other action that then leads to it being popped. Generally, I would say this is the preferable behaviour: the child view controller pops itself.

Otherwise, the child would have to call out to the parent (via a delegate or something) to say "pop!" which would then call `popViewControllerAnimated:`. This feels a little too convoluted for such a simple action.

Comment: It depends on what kind of "back" button you are providing, the one with left arrow comes from parent view controller.

Comment: In my case I *am* calling a delegate method on the parent, because the parent is a tableview "form", and my child is a tableview to browse, search and select from a list of possible values for a field on the parent form. So I could see it making sense both ways, although my gut says to do it in the child because that's where the user action happens (selecting a choice) that should close the view.

Comment: +1 to that. My gut also says if the action is in the child view, then the call to pop should be there too.